# second order ODE and Numerical integration

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I want to solve a second-order ODE

```
y''(x)+A*y'(x)+B*y(x)+c1*y(x)^2=0
```

I have written the code as

```
 B = 0.4; C2 = 0.5;F=0.6;


 sol2[A_] := 
 First@NDSolve[{y''[x] + A*y'[x] + B*y[x] + C2*y[x] == 0, y[1] == 1, 
    y'[0] == -0.2}, y, {x, 0, 1}]



   Plot[{Evaluate[y[x] /. sol2[0.2]], Evaluate[y[x] /. sol2[0.5]]}, {x, 
  0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {X, \[Theta][X]}]
```

and then want to calculate the Numerical integration of `3*y[x]+F*y[x]` from `0 to 1`how can I do the integration and plot it.

Comment: Syntax error: `F=0,6` Comma should be dot: `F=0.6`. And that is all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This system can be solved exactly using [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html).

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)
```

Use exact values for the known parameters,

```
B = 2/5; C2 = 1/2; F = 3/5;

eqns = {y''[x] + A*y'[x] + B*y[x] + C2*y[x] == 0, 
  y[1] == 1, y'[0] == -1/5};

sol = DSolve[eqns, y, x];
```

Verifying the solution,

```
eqns /. sol // Simplify

(* {{True, True, True}} *)
```

The solution is then

```
sol2[A_, x_] = y[x] /. sol[[1]] // FullSimplify

(* (E^(-(1/10) (5 A + Sqrt[-90 + 25 A^2]) x) (2 E^
      Sqrt[-(18/5) + A^2] + (-5 A + Sqrt[-90 + 25 A^2]) E^(
      1/10 (5 A + Sqrt[-90 + 25 A^2])) - 
     2 E^(Sqrt[-(18/5) + A^2] x) + (5 A + Sqrt[-90 + 25 A^2]) E^(
      1/10 (5 A + Sqrt[-90 + 25 A^2] (1 + 2 x)))))/(5 A (-1 + E^
      Sqrt[-(18/5) + A^2]) + Sqrt[-90 + 25 A^2] (1 + E^Sqrt[-(18/5) + A^2])) *)
```

Plotting,

```
Plot3D[sol2[A, x], {x, 0, 1}, {A, -1, 2},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"x", "A", "y"})]
```

[image]

or

```
Plot[Evaluate[Tooltip[sol2[#, x], #] & /@ Range[-1, 1, 0.2]],
 {x, 0, 1},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel ->
  (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"x", "y"}),
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Range[-1, 1, 0.25], LegendLabel -> "A"]]
```

[image]

The requested integral is

```
int[A_] = Integrate[3*y[x] + F*y[x] /. sol[[1]], {x, 0, 1}] // 
  FullSimplify

(* (8 E^(1/2 Sqrt[-(18/5) + 
     A^2]) ((1 + 5 A) Sqrt[-90 + 25 A^2]
       Cosh[A/2] - (1 + 5 A) Sqrt[-90 + 25 A^2]
       Cosh[1/2 Sqrt[-(18/5) + A^2]] + 
     45 Sinh[1/2 Sqrt[-(18/5) + A^2]] + (-1 + 
        5 A) (Sqrt[-90 + 25 A^2] Sinh[A/2] - 
        5 A Sinh[1/2 Sqrt[-(18/5) + A^2]])))/(5 (5 A (-1 + E^
        Sqrt[-(18/5) + A^2]) + 
     Sqrt[-90 + 25 A^2] (1 + E^Sqrt[-(18/5) + A^2]))) *)
```

Plotting,

```
Plot[int[A], {A, -1, 1},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"A", "int"})]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For the nonlinear equation,

```
eqns2 = {y''[x] + A*y'[x] + B*y[x] + C2*y[x]^2 == 0, 
   y[1] == 1, y'[0] == -1/5};
```

Use [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html)

```
sol2 = ParametricNDSolve[eqns2, y, {x, 0, 1}, {A},
   WorkingPrecision -> 15,
   NormFunction -> (Norm[#, 2] &)];

Plot3D[y[A][x] /. sol2, {x, 10^-3, 1 - 10^-3}, {A, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Integrate[y[A][x] /. sol2, {x, 0, 1}], {A, 0, 1},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"A", "int"})]
```

[image]

Comment: Halon thanks for your time. the answer is good but it does not work properly for non-linear equation  '{y''[x] + A*y'[x] + B*y[x] + C2*y[x]^2 == 0, y[1] == 1, 
  y'[0] == -1/5} ' which is my oragional equation

Comment: I used the equation you put in the definition of  `sol2`

Comment: sorry it was my mistake actually I want to solve a nonlinear equation shown in first equation

Comment: See edit for revised equation